# Error : "Activity does not extend android.app.Application" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I'm creating an AndEngine game for Android in eclipse & java. I created my own activity class and added it to application attributes in my Android manifest. But it said **"com.myname.projectname.Activity does not extend android.app.Application"**. It extends SimpleBaseGameActivity but I heard that it should work well in this status.

What may the problem be? And how can I solve this?

Comment: I suspect you have an error in your manifest.  Can you post it?

Comment: @Jules Sure, http://pastie.org/private/d5hndrdgkjwjyulvcxnwhg

Answer (score 0):

I think in your project , there is some `Application_class` and inside another class you are using , `Application_class` instance in your Activity , and that `Application_class` is not extending `Application` class .

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    public static Context appContext;


}
```